# Check if a string contains a value from one table

Tags: sql, oracle

so, I have a table t_type, that contains values :

**t_type :**

```
id | lib_type
--------------
1  | highschool
2  | University
3  | Unknown
```

I make a `SELECT` query into another table, that give me a full name (for example : Foch Highschool, University of Paris, random enterprise).

Then, I want to SELECT , in t_type, the row that fetch with the first seelct :

```
SELECT *
from t_type
where  lib_typ contains '%'||fullname||'%';
```

So, I f I got  Foch Highschool :

It must return `1 | Highschool`

If it is University of Paris :

It must return `2 | University`

And, if SELECT in t_type does not bring any lines,

it will return `3 | Unkown`

I found some samples, that show how to search, but with this :

```
SELECT *
from t_type
where  contains (lib_type, fullname ,1)
```

It will not work, because fullname will always be greater than lib_type.

What I want is, if that a part of fullname, contains a lib_type into my table, then return id and lib_type of the line.

Is this possible?

I Hope I'm clear, if not, tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're looking for something like this;

```
SELECT id, lib_type FROM (
  SELECT id, lib_type, 1 prio FROM mytable
  WHERE UPPER('Foch Highschool') LIKE UPPER('%'||lib_type||'%')
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, lib_type, 2 prio FROM mytable
  WHERE id=3
  ORDER BY prio
) z
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/533cd/2).

It selects the first lib type matching your input, and if none matches it gets the row with id 3.

It does so by setting prio 1 on any hits, and prio 2 on the default, then just sorting by prio and getting the first match.

Comment: Indeed, this works, but seems complicated, for setting a default value. But if I have to, I will. Tahnk you.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your question I think you have to do as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_type
WHERE  lib_type LIKE "YourResult%"
```

Where the string YourResult contains the text you are searching for;)

Comment: No, it it the contrary, we can't do it with a like, but if we can it should be `WHERE  "%YourResult%" LIKE lib_type` .But as we can't, I am blocked.